try catch in then still gives uncaught error
I'm fetching data from an API. I would like to handle both cases, when the response is valid JSON and when it is not.
return fetch( ... )
    .then(response => {
        let res
        try {
            res = response.json()
        } catch (e) {
            res = response.blob()
        }
        return res
    })

I thought this should work, but it doesn't. It throws
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', " ... "... is not valid JSON

What am I doing wrong?

response.json() returns a promise of the parsed JSON.

Similar situation, same explanation and solution: Why doesn't the try catch block catch the promise exception?

If you throw inside an async function, you let it return a rejected promise (object). So in the try you successfully get that object and it gets assigned. Noting goes wrong... except that you didn't add a catch handler for your promise.

You are dealing with Promises.  They have a built in .catch() function, which you can write a function for that error. Additionally, you should not rely on try and catch to determine how to process the data, you can you the Content-Type header within the request to determine the data type.
MDN Web Docs
return fetch( ... )
    .then(response => {
        if (response.headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/json')) {
            return response.json();  
        } else {
            return response.blob();  
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error:', error);
    });

